# Getting my password incorrect besides being correct

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I can't figure out why I'm getting out my password incorrect, my signup page is working properly.Everytime I try to login it shows login=incorrect password in my url.I tried to figure ot every possible issue online but nothing helped me.

```
    <?php 
    session_start();

      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include_once 'dbt.inc.php';

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

    //error handlers
    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
        header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'";
        $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($run);

        if ($result < 1) {
            header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=error");
            exit(); 
        }
        else{
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
                $hashedpasswordcheck = password_verify($password, $row['user_password']);
                if ($hashedpasswordcheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=incorrect password");
                    exit();
                }
                elseif($hashedpasswordcheck == true){
                    //log in user
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['user_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                    $_SESSION['user_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['user_username'] = $row['user_username'];
                    $_SESSION['user_password'] = $row['user_password'];
                    header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=success");
                    exit();

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
           else{
          header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=error");
         exit();
}



 ?>
```

Comment: how you are storing your password when user sign up? Which hash method your are using?

Comment: I'm using it by hashing the password and then storing it directly into the databse @prit.patel

Comment: Yes but which hashing method your are using? md5(), password_hash() which one?

Comment: I'm using pasword_hash() method @prit.patel

Comment: You should not escape your password as you are not using it in an sql statement. And using a prepared statement, you would not need to escape anything at all.

Comment: Btw.: You don't need to save the password in the session. Or do you want to do something with the password hash in the session?

Comment: yeah I removed that later

Comment: @yoshikkarnawat Please edit your question to include the output of `var_dump($password, $row['user_password']);` before the `password_verify()` call.

Answer (score -1):

If you get incorrect false responses from password_verify and you know it should be correct, make sure you are enclosing the hash variable in single quotes (') and not double quotes (").

In PHP anything that starts with a $ inside double quotes as a variable.

Comment: Nowhere in this code will the hash code be added manually, where a variable is being used inside a double quoted string.