# Getting Incorrect Password

Tags: php, sql

I can't figure out why I'm getting out my password incorrect, my signup page is working properly.Everytime I try to login it shows login=incorrect password in my url.I tried to figure out every possible issue online but nothing helped me.

```
    <?php 
    session_start();

      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include_once 'dbt.inc.php';

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

    //error handlers
    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
        header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=empty");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'";
        $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($run);

        if ($result < 1) {
            header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=error");
            exit(); 
        }
        else{
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
                $hashedpasswordcheck = password_verify($password, $row['user_password']);
                if ($hashedpasswordcheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=incorrect password");
                    exit();
                }
                elseif($hashedpasswordcheck == true){
                    //log in user
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['user_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                    $_SESSION['user_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                    $_SESSION['user_username'] = $row['user_username'];
                    $_SESSION['user_password'] = $row['user_password'];
                    header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=success");
                    exit();

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
           else{
          header("Location: ../main_login.php?login=error");
         exit();
}



 ?>
```

this is my signup code It is working completely fine, I don't see any errors in this code so if you see any please help me

```
 <?php 
if(isset ($_POST['submit'])){
    include_once 'dbt.inc.php';

    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

        //Error Handlers
    if(empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password)){

            header("Location: ../main_signup.php?signup=empty");
            exit();
    }
    else{
        //check if input characters are valid
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last)){
            header("Location: ../main_signup.php?signup=invalid first and last name");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            //check if email is valid
            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                    header("Location: ../main_signup.php?signup=invalid_email");
                    exit();
            }
            else{
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username='$username'"; 
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                if($resultCheck > 0){
                        header("Location: ../main_signup.php?signup=username already taken");
                        exit();

                }else{
                            //hashing the password
                            $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                            //insert the user into database
                            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_username, user_password) VALUES('$first','$last','$email','$username','$hashed_password ')";
                            $run = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                            header("Location: ../main_signup.php?signup=success");
                            exit();
                        }
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: ../main_signup.php");
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting my password incorrect besides being correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50620132/getting-my-password-incorrect-besides-being-correct)

Comment: You really shouldn't escape the passwords before hashing them. That will change the password. Are you escaping it on your registration page as well? Since you're just using the hash anyway, it isn't even necessary.

Comment: What's the length of the password column in your database?

Comment: I've kept it 1000

Comment: Various Characters

Comment: After adding password in my query $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username' AND  user_password = '{$password}'"; now I'm getting  login=error in my url

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with that code. Can you show us the code that handles and saves the passwords in the registration page? You should _not_ include the password in the query. Hashes are unique, so they will never match. Also, do a `var_dump($password, $row['user_password']);` and make sure they contain what you expect.

Comment: If you don't mind can we talk in personal please??

Comment: I don't have time for that. Update your question to include the information I asked for and me, or someone else, might be able to see if there's something wrong.

Comment: ok..wait I'll add up the sign up code!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a space following your hashed_password variable in your signup code.

```
'$username','$hashed_password ')";
```

Answer (score -1):

I see... your using password_hash....just replace every password hash with $hash = hash(sha512, $password). You can also add some salt but i wont recommend because its very unlikely for an same password.. Also if you want double hash it for security. Also who will insert value 1 for activated? You need to insert 1 in activated column in sql query in signup or else ot wont work. Also before escape of password string ...hash it the escape...

Solution:-(works for me)
       signup.php

```
    $first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
    $last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password1 = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $hashed_password);
```

Comment: I dont see bad in it

Comment: You are suggesting to use plain hash instead of password_hash .. that is from a security standpoint bad advise. No matter how strong a hash you use the solution is subject to rainbow attacks etc ..